# Há como exportar um app para teste sem o apple developer program ?

Tags: ios, swift

Estou concluindo um app em swift 2 IOS e gostaria de saber se há como exportar e instalar num iphone sem que tenha o apple developer program, tal como pode ser feito no android.

Comment: Sim..  basta compilar diretamente no aparelho. Ou vc que dizer que pretende distribuir em outros aparelhos sem precisar compilar cada um?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar uma conta de desenvolvedor, mas sem pagar os 99 USD. Dessa forma você continua sem poder publicar apps na AppStore, mas pode instalar o app no seu iPhone.

Pra isso, você pluga o iPhone no seu Mac e, no XCode, ao escolher o device, vai aparecer o seu iPhone lá... É preciso que a sua conta de desenvolvedor esteja vinculada ao projeto, mas se eu não me engano o XCode meio que te guia para você fazer isso. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Tem como você instalar sim e a partir do Xcode 7 não precisa mais pagar a licença!

1. No Xcode, você adiciona o seu Apple ID em Account preferences.
2. Selection o projeto que quer colocar no iPhone/iPad e o target no navegador do projeto.
3. No projeto, clique em General e escolha o seu nome na opção Team.
4. Só dar play. Se for a primeira vez de um dispositivo as vezes demora um pouco para funcionar e pode até dar um erro, espere mais um pouco e tente de novo.

Os aplicativos são instalados antes de você abrir, e podem ser abertos até mesmo depois de desconectar do computador. Vale lembrar que algumas funções, como o game center, não funcionam sem uma conta de desenvolvedor.

Mais info:
1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak
2)http://blog.ionic.io/deploying-to-a-device-without-an-apple-developer-account/

Answer (score 0):

Boas, Clever

Sem a conta de Apple developer program não é possível, bem até onde sei.

Também não podes simular um app do Xcode em seu iPhone esse tentei com o SWift 3 Xcode 8.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno mas eu tenho conta https://developer.apple.com e consigo testar o app no iphone plugado com o xcode. Porém não sou assinante do apple developer program, o qual tem que pagar $ 99,00. Como o desenvolvimento de app não é o meu forte, não queria gastar em vão com esta conta. Por isso questiono se há alguma forma de instalar o app em aparelhos de teste sem que tenha que pagar. O Android, por exemplo, eu posso repassar o app por email para quem que quiser e instalar como teste.

Comment: No Android e Windows Phone podes, ja na Apple sem a conta do developer program e impossível talvez com jailbreak consigas resolver.


http://www.techtudo.com.br/dicas-e-tutoriais/noticia/2014/04/o-que-e-jailbreak.html

Comment: Andreza, A conta apenas é vinculada caso exista a conta de Developer Program. Se não tiver não ira instalar, simular é o máximo que se pode fazer.

Comment: Cómo mencionei...pode instalar sim no dispositivo mesmo não tendo programa...apenas a conta ativa...pois isso eu fiz. Mas pelo visto enviar a outra pessoa não tem jeito sem aderir ao Apple developer program